# why wont this background image wont display html and css

Tags: html, css

I just started learning html and css and I cant figure out why the backround image wont show up when I run the file all I see is "first website" in the corner

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), url(images/dhmkbannan.png));
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">

</section>
```

Comment: It's not an image here, it's a gradient mixed with an image, it's invalid syntax, it's either `background-image: url(images/dhmkbannan.png);` or `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7));` but not both at the same time

Comment: It's perfectly OK to have a linear gradient and a url as images there, but use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied. It has a syntax error. There is a missing closing bracket on the linear gradient and a spurious closing bracket on the url.

Answer (score 2):

You have close the paranthese at wrong place.
`background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), url(images/dhmkbannan.png);`

Answer (score 1):

Your closing parenthesis is in the wrong place. You're providing the image url to the `linear-gradient` property, not to the `background-image` property.

Instead of `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), url(images/dhmkbannan.png));`

Try `background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7)), url(https://picsum.photos/500);`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7)), url(https://picsum.photos/500);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide an image in the `background-image` property

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this

```
background-image: url("images/dhmkbannan.png"), linear-gradient(#eb01a5, #d13531); /* W3C */
```

> **You close the parentheses in the wrong place Also, you should know about background layering**

**Layer Stack**

It should be noted that the first defined image will be the topmost in the stack. In this case, the image is on TOP of the gradient.

For more information about background layering please check this link http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering.

Comment: Nothing stops you from placing the background image below the gradient, as long the gradient has transparency applied to it